# Algorithm to sum ranges that lie within another separate range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sum, range

I have two sets of ranges, one is a single range of any length (A) and the other is a set of ranges (B) some or parts of which may or may not lie within the single range (A).

I need to calculate the sum of the ranges in (B) - whole or partial - that lie within the single range (A).

I am using Javascript.

Examples:

```
A = [20,40]<br>
B = [14,22],[24,27],[31,35],[38,56]<br>
Result = 2+3+4+2 = 11<br>

A = [120,356]<br>
B = [234,567]<br>
Result = 122<br>
```

I need an algorithm/function that will return the resulting sum.

I used an excelent range merging algorithm posted here previously, I'm hoping for a similar elegant solution for this problem.

(Appologies if there has been a misunderstanding.
I have been working on a function but my maths in a coding context isn't good, so my solution was to use non-maths code (It would be embarassing to post it here!). I hoped to get some help here to create a compact maths based solution)

Comment: Can we see what you have tried?

Comment: why do you get the results? what is the algo behind?

Comment: You don't actually want the sum of the ranges, you want the sum of the count of the numbers inside the initial range. That's a LOT easier than it looks, because you just need to unroll the ranges and count the total numbers that are within the first range. But I agree with @Keith , you should first post what you tried.

Comment: Ah. The examples I have worked out on paper and just show the desired results for a given input. I am new to the editor here.

Comment: in the first example A = [20,40] B = [24,27]  4 numbers `24,25,26,27` fall within the group. According to you only 3 number lie within the range. So, is the list left exclusive or right exclusive ?

Comment: Prasanna - part of 14,22 lies within 20,40,that is 20,22. 24,27 and 31,35 both lie completely within 20,40 and 38,56 lies partially within 20,40,that is 38,40.

Answer (score 1):

This is the ES5 compatible version I used, for anyone interested:

```
function getDelta(range, values) {
    return values.reduce(function(s,pair){
        return s + Math.max(0, Math.min(pair[1], range[1]) - Math.max(pair[0], range[0]));
    },0);
}
```

However I would only use it if you need IE backwards compatibility. I work in an environment that trails the current trends!

Answer (score -2):

You could take the delta of the sub ranges and adjust start and end value with the given range.

```js
function getDelta([start, end], values) {
    return values
        .filter(([l, r]) => r >= start &&  l <= end)
        .reduce((s, [l, r]) => s + Math.min(r, end) - Math.max(l, start), 0);
}

console.log(getDelta([20, 40], [[10, 11], [14, 22], [24, 27], [31, 35], [38, 56], [400, 500]]));
console.log(getDelta([120, 356], [[10, 11], [234, 567], [400, 500]]));
```

As proposed from *ChatterOne* in the comments, you could use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) with zero to prevent negative values.

```js
function getDelta([start, end], values) {
    return values
        .reduce((s, [l, r]) => s + Math.max(0, Math.min(r, end) - Math.max(l, start)), 0);
}

console.log(getDelta([20, 40], [[10, 11], [14, 22], [24, 27], [31, 35], [38, 56], [400, 500]]));
console.log(getDelta([120, 356], [[10, 11], [234, 567], [400, 500]]));
```

Comment: the difference could be negative ?

Comment: the answer assumes, the left value is smaller/equal then the right value.

Comment: The problem here is that if none of the numbers is in the range, you get the wrong count. Try it with the first range being `[10, 11]`, for example. BTW, think that questions that show no effort and only ask for code should not really get an answer.

Comment: @ChatterOne, that is not the specification, because: *"to calculate the sum of the ranges in (B) - whole or partial - that lie within the single range (A)."*

Comment: So, you think that if you have the first range as `[10, 11]`. getting `-63` is the right output?

Comment: @ChatterOne, that is not part of the given specification. and no it would be not right, but that was and is not the question. and i could add a sanity check to exclude this ranges.

Comment: Actually yes, that is the question, because it `may or may not lie within the single range`. But in the end it doesn't really matter, apparently someone is happy that someone else did his job in his place.

Comment: Ninas answer appears to be correct, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Will it work if the ranges in (B) are outside (A)? That is result = 0

Comment: it works now with filtering for ranges outsode of the wanted range.

Comment: `return values.reduce((s, [l, r]) => s + Math.max(0, Math.min(r, end) - Math.max(l, start)), 0);`

Comment: Just caught up with the discussion. I'll try it out.

Comment: That seems to work! I need to make it ES5 compatible but I'll have a go at that myself, I'll post it here or if I get stuck I'll be back. I think it would be useful for me to convert it because I need to get used to arrow functions. Plus I haven't used 'reduce' before, so that has been useful knowledge as well.